# What are the benefits accepting Islam as Religion?

Tags: practical-islam, respect

I want to know some knowledge about the Islam. So that I can preach it to other people.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly you should know that God says in the **Quran**:

> Do you order [the] people [the] righteousness and you forget yourselves, while you [you] recite the Book? Then, will not you use reason?[2:44]

Therefore first you should practice what you preach.

If you want to tell them about Islam tell them that if they worship God as one and carry out his commands they will have good in this world and an excellent reward in the hereafter.

Tell them about the five pillars of Islam which are obligatory upon every Muslim:

1. Testifying  that there is none worthy of worship But Allah and Muhammad(Peace Be Upon Him) is his messenger.
2. Establishing the prayer 5 times a day.
3. Paying Obligatory charity which is the zakat
4. Fasting in the month of Ramadan.
5. Going to pilgrimage(Hajj).

Tell them about the majors sins to avoid such as associating others with Allah, Murder, Black Magic, Not carrying out the pillars mentioned above when able to, illegal sexual intercourse, drinking alcohol, disrespect and disobedience to parents and more.

Tell them about the Last day when everyone will be judged according to their deeds and Allah will decide who will enter paradise and who will enter hell.

Tell them that if they obey Allah and his messenger according to what is in the **Quran** and the **Sunnah** then by Allah's will He will bestow on them paradise which is promised only to the believers and save them from hell-fire.

Also that the enjoyment of the life of this world is little compared to the enjoyment of the hereafter. [9:38]